# How can I get contract address of a contract from another contract?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix

Here how can I find the address of A within Test() function?

```
contract A {
    uint public target;
    function setTarget(uint _target) public {
        target = _target;
    }
}

contract B {
    A a = Test(0x123abc...);  // address of deployed A
    function editA() public {
        a.setTarget(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate? Your example is not enough to understand your question. Test seems more like a parent contract of A than an actual function.

Comment: I am not sure about that, I found the code in this [link](https://www.edureka.co/community/21910/is-it-possible-modify-variable-value-from-another-contract)

Comment: Well, you are storing a Test instance inside a A reference, so it must have some coorelation, either way @Petr Hedja's answer might be what youre seeking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the address by casting the `A` type to type `address`.

```
contract B {
    A a = Test(0x123abc...);

    funciton getAddressA() public view returns (address) {
        return address(a); // typecasting to `address`
    }
}
```